# libsvm - how to make grid.py faster?

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

LIBSVM has a python function `grid.py` that, to my understanding, applies parameter selection using a method called `grid-search`.

> Usage: grid.py [grid_options] [svm_options] dataset

How much time does it take ? I have a huge dataset (csv file with 80K lines), It's taking more then 24 hours till now. Is there a way to make the script faster ?

Comment: Did you run with **default** options?

Comment: Yes ! I run by default options.

Answer (score 1):

Limit **range**

```
-log2c {begin,end,step | "null"} : set the range of c (default -5,15,2)
-log2g {begin,end,step | "null"} : set the range of g (default 3,-15,-2)
```

reduce the number of n-fold cross validation

```
-v n : n-fold cross validation (default 5)
```

Of course, there still be need to optimize the code, but simply limit the range first.

**UPDATE**

Try **subset.py** to reduce data set then run **grid.py**. I will give you insight fast!

Comment: can you please give an example how can I take decision to limit range. Most of target columns I have is zero. Can this help to decide.

Comment: I'm not sure. First try to reduce `step`. 2 and -2 to more. for example, 4 and -4. and set -v 1 . Then see the log and determine what you are going to do.

Answer (score 1):

in grid.py you find the parameters

```
telnet_workers = []
ssh_workers = []
nr_local_worker = 1
```

where you can configure external helpers and the number of local threads. try to increase the number of local threads until your machine is (near) 100% loaded.